# How to combine header files and create a DLL

Tags: c++, dll, linker, dev-c++

How are *we* supposed to create a DLL, included with header files?

For example, a project using the raylib game library requires *raylib.dll* to be present with the output file.

The *raylib.dll* is included with the header files of the raylib game library.

Is that how are supposed to create a DLL and include header files into it?

I am using Dev C++ with a GCC compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's only a limited relation between the header files and the *creation* of the DLL. In particular, you use the word "linked", and header files are not linked. Header files are *included*, libraries are *linked*. Including happens *before* a compile, linking afterwards.

Header files can provide declarations for functions defined in the DLL. That tells the compiler that those functions actually exist (somewhere), so the compiler will ask the linker to find those functions. The linker in turn will find them in the library.

Comment: Sorry for the misuse of the word *link*. But, can you actually tell how to include header files with a DLL?

Comment: I've also corrected my question by replacing *linked* with *include*

Comment: @IneoSenigupta: The user of the DLL will just use `#include`. The author just needs to write the header files. That's all not very special. The tricky bit is actually compiling .cpp files into a DLL.

Comment: And how are we supposed compile .cpp files in a DLL?